# bundle products not in price index table , not visible

Tags: bundled-product

I have upgrade an magento shop from a very old system to magento 1.9.2. Bundle Products are not visible in the shop. I have search a lot of time and i have found out that bundle_products build no index in the catalog_product_index_price mysql table.

So i have edit the core product file for the products and rebuild the index for those products per hand. So the index in this table is build and the products are visible. Now when some user order some bundle products in the invoice for the order all product prices are zero. PayPal redirect with an error that the basket price is not the order price.

So, my work around is not really an option. But i have really no idea why bundle_products build no price index :( When i edit/create some bundle_product in the admin the fields price type and tax are disabled too - i think it is also not normal.